# Django Application

Tags: django, leaflet, openstreetmap

I have finished coding a Django App. In that app I have created two models in order to record some project information. Also I am showing project locations with markers on a map (OpenStreetMap) by using leaflet.js.

I will use this app only by starting an offline server like "python manage.py runserver". I am using "Firefox" to display the django app.

I really wonder if somehow the information that I keep in my django models or the markers on the OpenStreetMap is somehow reachable by others via on Firefox or leaflet.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in the same wi-fi network you can run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and then your application will be visible for everybody by typing `http://your-pc-up:8000`

If you want to make it public you have to buy domain (or register free domain) and put it in your vpc / free hosting. There are plenty of tutorial out there which show how to host an application.

This tutorial is really easy and straight forward: http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift reply. I believe I couldn't phrase well what I would like to ask. I actually don't want to release the tool online. I just would like to use it offline. What I wonder is since I am using firefox to display the tool am I exposing the database somehow to unwanted 3rd parties?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**ngrok service**](https://ngrok.com/) which gives you domain such as `https://c2757c5f.ngrok.io` and other users can visit it by accessing this url. In addition, this url can be visited from anywhere!

See more details by visiting [here](https://ngrok.com/)

If you want other users can visit you website from you local server, then you can run `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. Your app is visible to other users on same network by accessing this `http://your-ip:8000/`

You could know you ip by using `ifconfig` command on *linux* or *ubuntu*